# Is It A Best Practice To Pass Empty Map Purposely?

Tags: apex, map

Here's the scenario:

I've two different classes (say `ClassA` and `ClassB`) which will be calling a Static method (say `meth1`) of `ClassC`.

`meth1` has three arguments: `List<String> lstStr, Boolean bool and Map<integer,string> testMap`

The only way to differentiate between `ClassA` and `ClassB` is that `ClassB` doesn't create any `Map<integer,string>` but `ClassA` has.

meth1 will be executing logic only if the IF condition satisfies and following is the condition:

- If `testMap` is Empty or null then execute - when called from `ClassB`
- If `testMap` is not Empty and contains certain values then execute - when called from `ClassA`

I've done OR between the above two conditions in IF.

If I pass null from `ClassB` then I would get null de-reference error (since I've `!testMap.isEmpty()` and `containsKey()` in IF condition bullet 2).

So how feasible is it to purposely pass an empty `Map<integer,string>` from `ClassB` method (without affecting resource usage since I'll be having huge data in lots of other variables).

This will make things easier since I can use both `!testMap.isEmpty()` and `containsKey()` for `ClassA` and also check for `testMap.isempty()` for `classB`.

Is it even a good practice?

Comment: try with this condition `if(testMap != null && !testMap.isEmpty())`

Comment: Thanks @sarvesh - But this fails since passing null will cause de-reference error... And passing empty map will TRUE the condition != null... Since empty map is not null map

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: IMHO always pass instantiated collections, even if empty rather than passing null.  Code that references a map collection will generally use `if myMap.contains(someKey)...` or `for (SomeType t: myMap.values()) {..` logic anyway and hence do the right thing, even if map is empty.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to [overload methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/). You can create 2 methods with different parameters for your use case as below:

```
public class classC {

    public static Object meth1(List<String> lstStr, Boolean bool, Map<integer,string> testMap) {
        // logic
    }

    public static Object meth1(List<String> lstStr, Boolean bool) {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Depending on the parameters you pass, appropriate method will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas but I've ~100 lines of code in meth1... But I'll try to make a new common method which these two overloading methods can further call. Need heavy restructuring though

Answer (score 1):

Pass the empty map as a parameter and check if `map.isEmpty()` [Map documentaion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)

```
class c{
    static void method(List<String> lstStr, Boolean bool, Map<integer,string> testMap){
    if(!testMap.isEmpty()){
      //logic
    }
    else{
    }
 }
}

class B {
    //pass the empty map in method
    c.method(lstStr,true,new Map<integer,string>());
}

class A{
    //pass the data is map
    c.method(lstStr,true,testMap)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Sarvesh - This is exactly what I've done right now and that's the question :) Is it acceptable and best practice?

Comment: Yes it is the best way to handle map, or else if your map logic is completely different than you should create a separate method  with the same name as difference params mean - method overload, see salesforce-sas answer